# Why ngValue doesn't reflect model changes via ngKeypress

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to change a model value using `ngKeypress` event, but the `input` has an `ngValue` for the same `model`. When I press `ENTER` the model receives the value and the `ngValue` doesn't process it.

To reproduce:

- Create an input
- Add `ng-value="value"`
- Add `ng-keypress="change($event)"`
- On controller `change` method add this code: `if (event.keyCode === 13) $scope.value = new Date()`
- Note `ngValue` doesn't reflect the changes made by `change` method

Example: https://codepen.io/betonetotbo/pen/MmZJmg

In `angular 1.6.x` this doesn't occurs, only in `1.5.x`.

It's a bug?

Comment: I opened your sample and it works correctly. What are you expecting?

Comment: @quirimmo sorry, the example was running with angular 1.6, now I fixed it to version 1.5.8, try it again.

Comment: But what is the behavior that you are expecting and it is not happening?

Comment: @quirimmo yes, the previous version (with angular 1.6) was my expected behavior.

Comment: ok I got what you want to achieve, posting code in the answer that's easier, see if this is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

According to [issue 16006](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/16006) this is an expected behavior on angular 1.5.x.

- Angular 1.5.x = `ngValue` changes only the `value attribute` and not the `value property`
- Angular 1.6.x = `ngValue` changes `value attribute` and `value property`

In my case I solved creating an second model and used a `ng-model` to do what I need. Another solution is migrate to angular 1.6.

Answer (score 0):

The one you reported is a feature added only since angular 1.6 version.
You can achieve the same behavior with a little trick. Change your HTML in this way:

```
<input type="text" ng-value="getData()" ng-keypress="stuff($event)">
```

And inside your controller this function:

```
$scope.getData = () => {
  return $scope.value;
};
```

Is this what you were looking for?